# MATLAB- Function definition

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

How can i plot a function that has different definitions in different time intervals in MATLAB?

For example function is equal to t plus 1 for t in interval minus 1 to zero and equals t in interval zero to 1.We need to do shifting and scaling after defining the function. So please consider it while answering.

I have tried by defining **`t`** as an array `t = [-2:0.01:2]` and `f = zeros( length( t ) )` and then finding the positions in `f` corresponding to its values of `t` and assigning it values.
I have to multiply two signals ( which are shifted and sampled versions of the original signal). The code that i have written is not giving the desired output.

```
clc
clear
t=(-10:0.01:10);
y=zeros(size(t));
y(t>=-1 & t<=0)=-1*t(t>=-1 & t<=0)-1;
y(t>=0&t<=1)=t(t>=0&t<=1);
y(t>=1&t<=2)=1;
y(t>=2&t<=3)=-1*t(t>=2&t<=3)+3;
subplot(5,1,1);
plot(t,y);
axis([-5 5 -2 2]);
n1=input('enter the shifting parameter-');
n2=input('enter the scaling parameter-');
t=(t+n1)/n2;
subplot(5,1,2);
plot(t,y);
axis([-5 5 -2 2]);
n3=min(t);
n4=max(t);
p=-10:0.01:10;
y1=zeros(size(p));
y1(p>=-2 & p<=-1)=1;
y1(p>=-1&p<=0)=-1;
y1(p>=0&p<=1)=p(p>=0&p<=1)-1;
y1(p>=1&p<=2)=1;
subplot(5,1,3);
plot(p,y1);
axis([-5 5 -2 2]);
m1=input('enter the shifting parameter-');
m2=input('enter the scaling parameter-');
p=(p+m1)/m2;
subplot(5,1,4);
plot(p,y1);
axis([-5 5 -2 2]);
m3=min(p);
m4=max(p);
a1=max(n3,m3);
a2=min(n4,m4);
r=a1:0.01:a2;
y2=zeros(size(r));
y2=y(r<=a2&r>=a1).*y1(r>=a1&r<=a2);
subplot(5,1,5);
plot(r,y2);
axis([-5 5 -2 2]);
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried to your post, it will show you tried and it may help people to understand better your request and potentially help you.

Comment: I have updated the question and the code also.

Comment: The part where you define the function and assign result by finding the position of the input vector is not the most efficient but looks all right to me. It runs fine (without error) for me. This code produces 5 plots, at which stage are you not satisfied with the result ?

Comment: The final stage.I guess the final result in which the two functions are multiplied is not the one desired.Its not correct. Check it.
Run time error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but..

```
t = -1 : 0.01 : 1;
y = zeros(size(t));
y(t < 0)  = t(t < 0) + 1;
y(t >= 0) = t(t >= 0);
plot(t, y);
```

If you do not want to have a vertical line in the break point...

```
hold on;
plot(t(t < 0), y(t < 0));
plot(t(t >= 0), y(t >= 0));
hold off;
```

> like this y=-t-1 ; -1 < t < 0 y=t ; 0 < t < 1 y=2 ; 1 < t < 2 I

Just add a new interval

```
t = -1 : 0.001 : 2;
y = zeros(size(t));
y(t < 0)  = t(t < 0) + 1;
y(t >= 0 & t < 1) = t(t >=0 & t < 1);
y(t >= 1 & t <=2) = 2; 
plot(t, y);
```

Comment: I have to plot two given signals that i have plotted and are working correctly and then perform the shifting and scaling operation and then finally multiply the two signals to get the output signal. So basically i am having an error in the multiplying part.

Comment: Shifting and scaling horizontal or vertical?? If horizontal then, obvious, you can multiply only intersecting regions.

Comment: Horizontal shifting. Yeah i know, that's what i have done multiplying the intersecting region. But it is showing error in result.Try running the code once and maybe you will know the problem i am facing.

Comment: @ROGER the problem with multiplication is that your t-values should be the same, but when you do scaling - t values can be defined at different values. Probably you have to create vectors only before the multiplication, calculating values of the functions at the same points only.

Comment: Or, using a linear spline and a lot of data points, recalculate values of the functions at the same points.

Comment: But as we are taking the scaling and shifting parameters as an input from the user we don't know the exact interval and hence cannot define the function in the interval.

Comment: @Roger you can recalculate the intervals based on shifting and scaling parameters.

Comment: But that would be in terms of variables and very complicated too. Is there any other method by which we can implement this?

Comment: I have slightly edited the code and now it is working fine if we put scaling parameter as 1 and shifting parameter as zero. But if we add any other value it shows wrong results. why?

Comment: I just told you - it will partially work if scaling one and shifting is integer.. Because you functions will be defined at different and not equal t. You can not just multiply elements of the vectors in this case

Comment: I have done that, i have defined a new interval
r=a1:0.01:a2
and the i have multiplied the functions for only this interval. i am not exactly getting what you are trying to convey.

Comment: Do it like this `y2=interp1(t, y, r(r<=a2&r>=a1), 'linear') .* interp1(p, y1, r(r>=a1&r<=a2), 'linear');` just calculate enough data points in `t` and `p` for smooth curves.

Comment: The problem is not with the smoothness but with the error in the result. Have you tried running the code? Run it and you will know the error(run-time).

Comment: You do not read me. The smoothness is related to the spline interpolation. The code that I wrote above will calculate the values of both functions at the points. If you replace the one line of the code with that line - there will be no errors at all. But also I do not have any error messages with your code either.

Comment: I told you there will be no error messages.And if i used your line it showed 'Error using griddedInterpolant
The coordinates of the input points must be finite values; Inf and NaN are not permitted.'
There is a runtime error. The result is not correct. The code runs.

Comment: @ROGER because the array that you operate with has inf or NaN values. I can not reproduce it without knowing what numbers you are entering.

Comment: I didn't get it. Okay leaving aside my approach to the question. what would have been your approach if you would have been given this question to solve?

Comment: I wrote everything above. Shift, scale, but then calculate with the help of interpolations both functions at the same points of x-axis, multiply over overlapping region. Sorry, 2 AM, I have to sleep.

Comment: Interpolation means we know the value of function at certain points and we are using that info to estimate the function value at other points. In this case we know y on t so we used this info to plot the function alue on r. Right?

Comment: Yes. Or, if you have a lot of data points, the multiplication of the close points for two functions will introduce only a small error.